# Do I need to disclose use of Google Play billing library in the data safety form?

Tags: android, google-play

I've implemented in-app purchases in my app by using the Google Play billing library. I've implemented it as per the guidance [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#java). This just a basic one-time purchases, and I don't store the purchase tokens or pass them to backend server or anything like that.

Looking at the data safety form in the Play store, there's a few questions around this area:

1. *Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?* Yes/No
2. *Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit?* Yes/No
3. Under the: Financial Info > Other Financial info section: *Is this data collected, shared or both?

   **Collected** This data is transmitted off the user's device, either to you (the developer) or a third party. This includes data that is processed ephemerally, or stored for longer.
   ...AND/OR... **Shared**
   This data is transferred to a third party, either on or off the user's device*

My initial thoughts were the answers to the questions are:

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. Collected+Shared

But I'm not sure if this is correct. Thinking about it, what information is my app actually collecting/sharing? I'm just using the billing library to say "Does this user own sku X" or listen out when the library says "Hey, this person just purchased sku X". I'm not capturing or storing any kind of payment details or transaction history etc.

Can anyone offer their thoughts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to the policy guidelines of Google Play, and not a specific programming question. Stack Overflow is intended for programming questions.

Comment: @JeremyCaney - Apologies for a breaching the policy guidelines. I guess there is still a 'programming question' element to the question though. For example, if the purchase token is nothing but a meaningless GUID, then I don't feel like this is financial information. If it instead it contained more information about the name of the user, how much they paid, what card type etc, then this certainly would be considered financial information.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions

Comment: there's no programming question here. you're asking what you should enter for a form on another site, which is something which can change at any given time and nobody here can definitely tell you what will be accepted/what is correct and what isn't

Comment: `Understand data collection & data sharing -> Sometimes apps may redirect you to a different service to complete a certain action. For example, an app may direct you to a payment service such as PayPal, Google Pay, or another similar service, to complete a purchase. In these cases, the app developer does not need to declare the data collected by the other service if: The app does not access this information, and You provide this information directly to the other service ...`
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/11416267?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cdata-collection

Answer (score 4):

First off - I definitely recommend going through this doc - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469
Especially the **What developers need to declare across data types** section.

To a certain amount these are still murky waters, as this feature is new and Google is still figuring out which services go where. If you are not sure and want to be correct I would contact google support directly.

As to points:

**Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?**

- Definitely yes. There is an option later - Ephemeral processing - that says that it is being only used real-time and is not collected for a longer.

**Is all of the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit?**

- Depends on the library. Haven't gone through it and hopefully someone will fill in the blanks here. My first guess would be yes, as google probably encrypts it.

**Is this data collected, shared or both?**

- I would pick only collected, yet again for Ephemeral processing and also following lines stated in the documentation I mentioned earlier

> The following types of data transfers do not need to be disclosed as
> 'sharing':
>
> - Service providers. Transferring user data to a 'service provider' that processes it on behalf of the developer.
> - 'Service provider' means an entity that processes user data on behalf of the developer and based on the developer’s instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did contact Google with this question, but got the following response:  "please note that our team cannot comment or assist in issues related to policy issues."

Comment: @pledgeX I received the same answer when I asked for confirmation about a scenario which is basically the same as yours. And when I asked about the Billing Library's influence on the Data Safety section in a Google Webinar the question was not answered... :( It's really difficult to do things right.

Comment: @Jiří Petera Thank you for your thoughts. Why would you say "definitely yes" regarding the question whether data is collected? The doc says "“Collect” means transmitting data from your app off a user’s device." But in this specific scenario there is actually no data coming from the app that is transmitted. There is just a request to the library asking whether the current user (that is unknown to the app) made a purchase (and the result is not stored). So the Play Store transmits data to ME via the Billing Library and not the other way round... It really is confusing... :/

Comment: @flauschtrud It is essential to understand what Ephemeral processing means. It basically means, that you're using data only for a few seconds to do X and then discarding them. And google play billing does exactly that. 
So basically, if you only use any data one time and then throw it away. It should be marked as Collected + Ephemeral processing. 
With that you are saying: "Hey, we are using these data, just to do some action and never storing them."

Comment: From the F.A.Q:  It depends on the nature of your integration with the payment service. If your app uses a payment service such as PayPal, Google Pay, Google Play's billing system, or similar services to complete payment transactions, you don’t need to declare collection of the data that the payment service collects in connection with its ... https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmy-app-uses-an-external-payment-service-to-enable-financial-transactions-does-my-app-need-to-disclose-financial-information-like-credit-card-info-in-its-safety-section

Comment: `I would pick only collected` NO!!! You send it to Google, not to your own server, it's collected and **ALSO IT'S SHARED** with a third party - GOOGLE!

Comment: @ewin.str I believe if all of us use Billing library then usually all of use Firebase Analytics which automatically collects Purchase History in your app: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11582702 So your app still collects and shares this info with Google and you need to specify it in Data Safety that there is Purchases History is used for Analytics

Comment: @user924 yes you're right, a couple months ago I had to fix my declaration and state that the data is shared.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are correct, it is:

1.Yes

2.Yes

3.Collected+Shared

Comment: Based on the question, it doesn't seem like the OP is _just_ looking for confirmation of the answers, but the _reasoning_ behind them. Can you provide feedback on the specific issues they're struggling with, and how that informs these answers?